# What does 飼っとっと mean?

Tags: conjugations, dialects

For example:
ポニーを一応飼っとっとです.

The speaker is from Kumamoto. I'm guessing its a dialect, but struggling to understand the meaning.

Comment: Could you provide a link to where you heard or read this sentence? It would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resources

I looked on the following two websites that provided an overview of some Kumamoto dialect vocabulary and searched for the construction in your sentence.

- [Narit (`Ctrl+F` とっと)](http://www10.plala.or.jp/narit/kmt/kmt_ben1.html)
- [Kumamoto Kokufu (`Ctrl+F` トット)](http://www.kumamotokokufu-h.ed.jp/kumamoto/hougen/k_h-1ran.html)

### Meaning of 「とっと」

The definition of とっと and some of the sentences and their standard Japanese (標準語{ひょうじゅんご}) equivalents I found on the sites:

*Definition of トット（標準語：～ているの）*

> アットット，イットット，ウットット
>
> 会っているの，行っているの，売っているの

*Definition of ダランゴツ（標準語：話にならない、ばかげている）*

> ナアンバ**言うとっと**かダランゴツ
>
> 何を**言ってるの**話にならない

*Definition of ナシテ（標準語：なぜ、どうして）*

> ナシテ　**オゴットット**ナ？
>
> なぜ**怒っているの**？

### Translating your original sentence

From the definition and usage above, it's clear that「飼っとっとです」is「飼っているのです」in standard Japanese and the meaning would be "I currently own (a pony)."

However, I couldn't really make a lot of sense of the grammar of the sentence. For one, you would expect the particle「を」for owning a pet, e.g.「犬・猫・ハムスターを飼っています」. Next,「一応」could mean "just in case" or "for once" or even "for now" depending on the context. Not to say that it doesn't make sense in this sentence, but I suspect the person may have said「一頭{いっとう}」instead, because「頭」is the counter for a lot of animals, although one could argue that for a smaller animal like a pony, the counter「匹{ひき}」would be more appropriate.

If you had a link to the original dialogue, I could have another go at the transcription and translation.

Comment: That makes complete sense, as the leading question is 「飼ってるんですか？」
If you're interested, it is from an episode of 相席食堂 and the episode is はるな愛kaba.ちゃんの旅 (around 35 min mark, available on JP Netflix).

I think I made the question more confusing by trying to add more context. The speaker doesn't actually say 「ポーニーが飼う」as it is implied. I realise now that this is incorrect and I should have writted「ポーニーを飼う」instead.
Thank you for such an in depth answer.

Comment: @Ira Um, pony is always spelled as ポニー, never ポーニー. When I saw ポーニーが飼っとっと, I thought ポーニー was a person name ("It's Pornie who owns it" or something). Pony didn't even come to my mind.

Comment: @naruto that's a good point, in English the o in pony is long so I didn't realise the OP's Japanese spelling was incorrect.